# Window.scroll error when combined with section padding

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my html code I have something like this:

```
<section>
    <!-- Some things -->
    <div background-image: "image" style="padding: calc(45px + 1vw) 0 10px 0;">
        <!-- List of items. Each element has a padding bottom -->
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    <!-- Some things -->
</section>
```

Then I have a function in my javascript that allows me to go to the desired section by clicking on the links in the navbar:

```
function goTo(daAttivare) {
  const targetSection = document.getElementById(daAttivare + "_Page");
  window.scroll({
    top: targetSection.offsetTop,
  });
}
```

The padding top calc(45px + 1vw) causes an error in the window.scroll which scrolls the page 1px less when I go to the second section. A row of px from the first section is then still visible.
Replacing calc(45px + 1vw) with a fixed size in px or eliminating the bottom padding fixes the problem but I don't like either solution. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: please post the  full code

Comment: I am attaching the code on github. I hope you can help me solve the problem. Thanks in advance. https://github.com/Manux895/EsameDiStato.git